# How can I determine the type of UAC prompt that would result if I relaunch with elevation?

Tags: winapi, uac

I have an application where running with elevation is beneficial, but not essential. So, the application decides at runtime whether to relaunch itself with elevation or to stay as a non-elevated process.

In most cases, it will be run by a user who has no access to admin rights. That is, if I trigger a UAC prompt, the user will get a prompt that asks for admin credentials they do not have, and they cannot run the application (this is the outcome I wish to avoid).

However, if the user does have access to admin rights, they will get a UAC prompt that is a simple yes/no, and those users can then run the application with elevation, and various beneficial things follow.

So, in order to decide whether to relaunch with elevation, the application needs to know what kind of UAC prompt would result. A yes/no one (ok to relaunch) or a prompt-for-credentials one (not ok - stay as non-elevated).

It's not simply a matter of looking in the local administrators group - the user might have access to admin rights by virtue of Active Directory group memberships (possibly nested), but this application needs to decide whether to elevate or not in contexts where it can't talk to AD. Cached credentials may mean the current memberships in AD might not be relevant anyway.

Any ideas? It's a tricky one to describe, and a tricky one to search on.

As a side issue, I think `Regedit.exe` behaves in this way (prompting if it would be a yes/no, running without elevation otherwise). This implies that what I'm trying to do is possible.

If it helps, this application is part of a suite that includes a service running as `SYSTEM`, and the application can communicate with the service. So, if the service could look up this info somehow, that would be a useful answer. However, if there's a way the application itself (non-elevated) could determine this, that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Regedit uses `requestedExecutionLevel=highestAvailable` in its manifest. This runs the process un-elevated in "over-the-shoulder" UAC dialog scenarios.

Assuming you are using `asInvoker` in your manifest, you would need to launch a small helper application when doing the elevation (or use the RunAs verb to execute yourself).

If you don't want to do it this way, you could perhaps look at `TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN` in the process token.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! highestAvailable may be the key piece of info that I didn't know about and so couldn't search for - I'll experiment with that, but it looks like it might do what I'm after without needing to decide in code at all...